# SchemaSpy for SQL Server using nightly build

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, schemaspy

I would like to automate SchemaSpy as part of a nightly build against a SQL Server database.

I am unsure exactly how to go about this as there seems to be java sql server drivers missing when I go to generate.

Could anyone give me a step by step run through of how to run schemaspy in this context please?

Comment: Specifically what information about your database are you looking to obtain? There may be other tools that can be automated easier. Also, what build tool/ system are you using?

Comment: I want to generate a Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD).  MsBuild/TfsBuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler for Microsoft SQL Server](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a command-line program that can generate a database diagram of your Microsoft SQL Server database. Your build system can invoke the SchemaCrawler command line. SchemaCrawler gives you "grep" options to include and exclude tables and columns from the diagram.

In practice, what I have found is that outputting a text file of the database schema is useful too, when done as part of the build. This way, you can check the text file into your source code control system, and have a version history of how your schema has evolved over time. SchemaCrawler is designed to automate this too, from the command-line.